# Hive metastore update

Tags: hadoop, hive, metadata

I have a script running which creates hive tables, loads data int them and at the end deletes those tables for given date.

When I run same script again I get error as "Table already exists" hive metadata is getting updated late.

Can someone advise ?

Comment: Are the tables external?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause may be there are Other Hive jobs are using the same table names.

**You can try below**

1. CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] xyz
2. IF OBJECT_ID('xyz', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE xyz;
3. To Check metastore status

   ```
   service hive-metastore status
   ```
4. In case it is not started/dead then run

   ```
   service hive-metastore start
   ```

Please refer this link for more information on External tables [Hive: Create Table and Partition By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13800360/hive-create-table-and-partition-by)